# Dropdown button clicked once but functioning multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have this HTML code (using Bootstrap)

```
<div class='dropdown'>
    <button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'>Choose to do sth</button>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
        <li><a href='#' class='do-sth'>Eat</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='do-sth'>Play</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='do-sth'>Sleep</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My JavaScript code

```
$(".do-sth").click(function() {
    alert($(this).text())
})
```

The code itself works fine. However, it it wrapped inside a more complex code. The page could get refreshed with ajax, but the part of this dropdown list is not refreshed.

When the page is refreshed, if I click one of the dropdown option, the alert box will should show up twice. Then if I refresh the page again and click one of the dropdown option, the alert box will show up three times. Etc.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens? It seems to get fixed if I regenerate this dropdown button code part every time when I refresh the page, but I really do not want to do that.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of the code it's hard to be 100% certain, but almost certainly the code you mentioned:

```
$(".do-sth").click(function() {
    alert($(this).text())
})
```

is being executed every time your page is refreshed, and adding more and more event handlers to the page. If you run this code multiple times it keeps on adding more and more event handlers, it doesn't overwrite the previous ones you declared.

Comment: Yes exactly! I was attaching the event handler another time in my ajax code when I refresh the page...I corrected that and it works perfectly fine now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Feiiiiiiiiiiiii if this answer helped you please remember to accept it, and/or upvote - thanks.